# CSS can't use font-size attribute?

Tags: html, css, font-size

So I have a bit of code that I've been trying to do for an hour. I know I must be making a stupid mistake, but CSS won't change font-size no matter what I put.

```
  <div class="top">
   <div style="width:460px;float:right;">
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      Username:&nbsp;<input class="login" type="text" maxlength="30" />
      &nbsp;Password:&nbsp;<input class="login" type="password" />
      &nbsp;<input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

The error lies with the text- "Username" and "Password." I don't know what to do! Here's my style code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.top{
    margin:-8px;
    height:21px;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    background-color:#313131;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:3px;
    padding-right:8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #6b6b6b;
  }
  input.login{
    height:18px;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    font-size:12pt;
    border-width:0px;
    width:100px;
  }
  input.button{
    height:18px;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    border:2px solid #6b6b6b;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
</style>
```

I've even tried putting the words in `<span>`'s and setting those inline, and in the style tags, but they don't work! Here's my full document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" >
<style type="text/css">
  div.top{
    margin:-8px;
    height:21px;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    background-color:#313131;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:3px;
    padding-right:8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #6b6b6b;
  }
  input.login{
    height:18px;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    font-size:12pt;
    border-width:0px;
    width:100px;
  }
  input.button{
    height:18px;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family:sans-serif, verdana;
    border:2px solid #6b6b6b;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
      <div class="top">
       <div style="width:460px;float:right;">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
          Username:&nbsp;<input class="login" type="text" maxlength="30" />
          &nbsp;Password:&nbsp;<input class="login" type="password" />
          &nbsp;<input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**I just guess I needed to change the font-size in the font, as those were what the font was inheriting...? I don't know. Well, at least it works! :P**

Comment: What do you want the username and password text to look like?

Comment: This works in "quirks mode" btw. (That means if I don't include the `<!DOCTYPE>`)

Comment: @Paul Grime I want the username and password to be 12pt, but since that didn't work, I tried every single value- 20, 22, 10, 16. But it didn't react to any of those changes (I changed the sizes via the "div.top" class)

Comment: Ok, in that case I have suggested an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure from your question, but it sounds like you're trying to change the size of "Username" and "Password" text.

Your text belongs to the `<form>` element, but you are changing the `font-size` property on your `<input>` elements. Test whether adding the following rule to your CSS makes a difference:

`form { font-size: 20pt; }`

Note: I changed `12pt` to `20pt` because you're already inheriting `div.top { font-size: 12pt }`.

**Edit:**

Since that worked, I am editing in the best solution by Paul, which is to wrap your text in `<label>` elements and use CSS to set the `font-size` by class:

```css
 label.input {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

The HTML uses this new style as follows:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <label class="input" for="username">Username:</label>&nbsp;
    <input id="username" class="login" type="text" maxlength="30" />&nbsp;
    <label class="input" for="password">Password:</label>&nbsp;
    <input id="password" class="login" type="password" />&nbsp;
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

What browser are you testing this in? This works for me in WebKit and FireFox. I suspect that the issue you're having may be related to the outer container div not being closed.

Comment: Not in your sample code. Paul Grime's answer is good. You could ditch those non-breaking spaces too in favor of a margin.

Comment: That is, there are two divs, and only one of them is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, what I've done is turned your Username and Password text into `<label>`s as this is more informative semantically. Using the `for` attribute, this also has the added benefit that you can click on the `<label>` text and the associated input field will receive focus. The associated fields must have an `id` set for this to work that matches the `for` attribute.

The CSS declares styling for `<label>` tags with a class of `input`:

```css
  label.input {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

And the html uses this new style with the `<label>` tag:

```
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label class="input" for="username">Username:</label>&nbsp;<input id="username" class="login" type="text" maxlength="30" />
        &nbsp;<label class="input" for="password">Password:</label>&nbsp;<input id="password" class="login" type="password" />
      &nbsp;<input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```